# ImageIO not working on Ubuntu

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu, javax.imageio

I have the following java code, which writes an image to a byte array then back into an image:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("1.png"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi,"png",baos);
byte[] img = baos.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
BufferedImage bif = ImageIO.read(bais);
```

On OS X, this works perfectly fine, but on Ubuntu, bif (the final image) becomes null at the end, meaning there is a problem reading from the ByteArrayInputStream.  I'm using the oracle jdk in both cases and don't know what's going on.

Edit: More evidence that I'm going insane:  I printed the img byte array to a file using a FileOutputStream on Ubuntu and OSX, then diffed the two files, and they are exactly the same.  This means either the ByteArrayInputStream is different or (more likely) the second ImageIO.read isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Any type of `Exception` thrown?

Comment: Nope, bif is just null at the end.

Comment: Is something useful in the byte-array img? It could be empty or not a valid PNG (for some problem with the codec maybe). You should output the array and probably post it too (or the first bytes at least, to identify the PNG-header).

Comment: Good point.  I just diffed the output of img to a file on both OS X and Ubuntu, and while both are definitely PNGs, the files do differ somewhat significantly...they're binary so it's difficult to tell, but their relative sizes are 484649 (osx) and 374978 (ubuntu)

Comment: Is this Ubuntu desktop or Ubuntu server?

Comment: This is Ubuntu Server I believe.

Comment: @codersarepeople: Interesting difference, but both sizes are big enough for valid PNGs. I thought that maybe where was written something invalid. But if the header looks OK and the content is there, I have no idea why the new buffered is null.

Comment: Ok I'm being dumb.  I was accidentally using different images.  Now when I diff, the two img byte arrays are exactly the same.  So clearly the issue is in the ImageIO.read. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu server is usually running in headless mode which can cause problems with java image manipulation.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html

Try tweaking your jvm start-up settings to allow running headless and it should fix it.

Comment: I've been bitten by that one before, glad to help.